# Creating a new tag and changing/deleting it, reputations to create a tag seems too low

Tags: discussion, support, tags, tag-synonyms

It seems obvious that ***either*** the OP of this question,  ["Secretariat" vs. "Directorate"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/294929/secretariat-vs-directorate) created the tag ***or*** another user created it and it has been abandoned.

1. What's the right procedure to request a change or deletion of the tag? It should be ***spelling***, not [***speeling***](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/speeling/info).
2. There is one tag called ***orthography*** and do we need another tag?
3. Currently any user with [300 reputations](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) can create a tag. I think it is too low considering the fact that there are not many tags to be created. Wouldn't it be a good idea to put it at around [2,000](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit) at which you can edit questions and answers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can flag the question, but there are actions which can be done without needing moderators to deal with them.

With 2000 rep, you can edit the tag to be the correct one. If the tag only appears on one question (which can be verified by hovering over it) then the incorrect tag will be cleared up and will no longer exist. This doesn't happen immediately, it probably needs an overnight script; or that may be weekly. But it will happen. With less than 2000 rep, you can suggest the edit.

[spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) is already a synonym of [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography), and anyone who creates a question with tag [spelling](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/spelling) will find that it's changed to [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) automatically. With 2500 rep you can suggest tag synonyms. In this case, although *speeling* could be a synonym of [orthography](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/orthography) it's best to correct it since *speeling* is obviously wrong. [In fact it appears the user himself did this and then didn't like *orthography*.]

Tag creation is supposed to be moderated by 10k users in the ["new tags"](https://english.stackexchange.com/tools?tab=stats) tool. (At the bottom of that page; it's 10k-only). I've corrected *speeling* and *pharases* and dealt with the new [coin-a-term](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coin-a-term) which is obviously a synonym of [neologism](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neologism) along with [coin](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/coin).

To alter a privilege would be a network-wide change and unlikely to happen. But you could suggest it on meta.stackexchange.com. It could be worth asking about the rationale for setting the privilege threshold so low.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now I understand it.